# Activeadmin Destroy Record with Exception Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound in Admin [404]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I've configured Elasticsearch in my Rails application API and for Post model, it's working properly and I'm using `@post.destroy!` to delete a specific record without any problem, but when I'm trying the same through Activeadmin panel destroy action (I tried default destroy action and custom controller -> destroy action ), **here what's happening is deleting the record properly from db but after deleting it throws an exception**:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound in Admin::PostsController#destroy

[404] {"found":false,"_index":"posts","_type":"post","_id":"1802","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried all custom callbacks which mentioned in [elasticsearch-model documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) but the only one solution I found is by using `begin .. rescue` statement:

```
@deleted = false
begin
  @post.destroy!
rescue
  Post.find_by(:id => id).present? ? @deleted = false : @deleted = true
  #delete successful action here if @deleted == true
end
```